# Windows Server 2008 R2-Command Prompt-php7ts.dll is missing

Tags: iis, 64-bit, command-prompt, windows-server-2008-r2, php-7.3

In Windows Server 2008 R2 i installed php 7.3 using with web platform installer on IIS 7.5.
After installation In command prompt i ran this command :

> php -i|find "PHP Version"

But i got this error :

[image: php7ts.dll is missing]

> php7ts.dll is missing

How can i fix this error?
In php folder in this path(`C:\Program Files\PHP\v7.3`) i could n't find `php7ts.dll`

Comment: Ideally you should download PHP from https://windows.php.net/download/

Comment: @Lex Li Can we trust on web platform installer?

Comment: My personal opinion is that Web Platform Installer is dying. The most reliable way is to manually set things up.

Comment: @Lex Li Can i download php7ts.dll from else where & put it in php folder?

Comment: @Lex Li In this link(https://windows.php.net/download/) i couldn't find v 7.3.7; Also i don't know my php is ts or nts; Where can i download v 7.3.7 for windows?

Comment: @SilverLight lets chat: [https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204257/ashkan](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204257/ashkan)